# Why does this query script return a fatal error?

Tags: php, pdo, fatal-error

I get a fatal error on executing the query below:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 50');
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $result['name'] . ':' . strip_tags($result['message']);
    }
```

Returns:

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

I set my $db like this:

```
try {$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Comment: Did you forget to initalize $db?

Comment: How are you setting $db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting an error because of the execution of the query.  The query in fact will never try to execute

This error -

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

tells you that `$db` is not an object.

Either it was never instantiated, or it was instantiated within a different scope.

Comment: Indeed, I accidently put the $db in an if-statement that would only be executed on a post request. Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$db has not been properly initialized in the scope you are using it.

You might want to try putting a `global $db;` before both of them to see if it is a scope problem.

```
global $db;
try {$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');}
catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}

global $db;
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments LIMIT 50');
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $result['name'] . ':' . strip_tags($result['message']);
    }
```