# PDO query inside PHP function issue

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

I have the following code:

```
function user_name($id) {
    $eqpt_name1 = $this->sql->query("SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = $id AND `f_id` = 1");
    $eqpt_name1_2 = $eqpt_name1->fetch();
    $name1 = $eqpt_name1_2['f_val'];

    $eqpt_name2 = $this->sql->query("SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = $id AND `f_id` = 2");
    $eqpt_name2_2 = $eqpt_name2->fetch();
    $name2 = $eqpt_name2_2['f_val'];

    $name3 = $name1 . " " . $name2;

    return $name3;
}
```

what it does is take the provided user id ($id) and gets the First ($name1) and Last ($name2) name of the user and then outputs it.

I call it by doing the following

```
$username = user_name($_SESSION['user_id']);
```

`$_SESSION['user_id']` is `1`, for example.

When I manually put the code in a PHP file, it works fine. But when I use a function so I can use it globally over the entire site so I don't have to have that long query code on every page, Apache gives me this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on a non-object

I've never written a function that has a query in it before and not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done to solve this problem? Have you performed a search on the internet and on SO for the error message? What did you find?  What has caused that error for others? What fixed their problems?

Comment: i did look around. all the other examples are using prepared statements and i have yet to master that. without the function, and hard coding this set of code in a page it works fine. not sure why the query won't work properly in a function.

Comment: This isn't an error with your query or with the prepared statement.  Did you try looking for what causes the "call to a member function ... on an non-object" error?

Comment: yes. apparently the issue was that i wasnt globallizing $this which is my database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this query script return a fatal error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501364/why-does-this-query-script-return-a-fatal-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by how you’re calling it, that’s just a global function; `$this` won’t be defined, and so you can’t use `$this->sql`. If you have a global variable called `$sql`, tell PHP that you’re using it:

```
function user_name($id) {
    global $sql;

    $eqpt_name1 = $sql->query("SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = $id AND `f_id` = 1");
    $eqpt_name1_2 = $eqpt_name1->fetch();
    $name1 = $eqpt_name1_2['f_val'];

    $eqpt_name2 = $sql->query("SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = $id AND `f_id` = 2");
    $eqpt_name2_2 = $eqpt_name2->fetch();
    $name2 = $eqpt_name2_2['f_val'];

    $name3 = $name1 . " " . $name2;

    return $name3;
}
```

Also, you’re using PDO, so why aren’t you using prepared statements? And you can simplify things a little further, too:

```
function user_name($id) {
    global $sql;

    $query = $sql->prepare('SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = :id AND `f_id` IN (1, 2) ORDER BY `f_id`;');
    $query->execute(array(':id' => $id));

    return implode(' ', $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
}
```

Comment: still learning prepared statements. so i need `f_id` 1 and 2 as 1 is first name and 2 is last name. so would i change the OR to AND?

Comment: @JesseWilliamSzypulski: See update, you can just use `IN`. That part has less to do with PDO and more to do with SQL; the PDO part is the `:id` thing. It defines a placeholder for the ID, and then the query is executed with `:id` bound to `$id`.

Comment: i tried your prepared statement. it works. but it returns FIRST LAST LAST for some reason. its putting the last name twice.

Comment: your revision fixed the issue. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

The construct **$this->** should be used inside objects to indicate reference for "self" instance.

There is no **$this** inside a function. You probably using a global variable that is an instance of a PDO class. You should use the $GLOBALS['varname'] in spite of $this or create a local instance of PDO inside your function.

```
function name()
{
    $pdo = new PDO( /* args */ ); // or use a global one 
    //$pdo = $GLOBALS['pdo'];
    $statement = $pdo->sql->query( "SELECT `f_val` FROM `profiles` WHERE `u_id` = ".$pdo->quote( $id )." AND `f_id` = 1" );
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchColumn(); // return first column
}
```

Also noted taht you doing two statements to concatenate a name. You could do all this thing direct into one SQL query just for knowleage.